# a way to figure out how much space will be free if table will be shrink-ed

Tags: database, informix, truncate

I have some table which act as a queue that might hold millions of rows for some time, then it gets emptied when the queue get processed. apparently, the db will allocate more space to this table as it is grows, and there will be a need to truncate the table especially when the queue get cleared to free the allocated space in the table.

What I am looking to do is checking how much space I will get if I shrink-ed the table, in other words, I want to know how much free space is already allocated to the table. I have tried

```
oncheck -pt <db>:<tables>
```

and it doesn't seem to give much helpful information.

Comment: Why worry?  If the table grows, the space will be reeallocated.  If it got to ten times as big as it should ever be, truncate it and let it grow naturally.  What did you get from `oncheck`? Why didn't it help?  The answer about how much space will be freed depends on how the table is indexed and fragmented, and the options to TRUNCATE.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler the issue here is sometimes the application that process the queue goes down which mean that the table will contains millions of rows and will get allocated GBs of space, while all I need for normal functioning is a couple of thousands row, that where I need to truncate the table to reclaim the space. However, I need to know how much I will get before I actually truncate the table.

Comment: Why do you need to know how much space you'll get?  If you think it is holding too much storage and it's empty, truncate it.  When I run the `oncheck` command on the largest table in a tiny database, I get 4 separate records with 'physical pages' and values between 4 and 8 (like I said, it's tiny).  I could sum those up (4+8+8+6 = 26).  After a truncate, there might still be some pages allocated, so I might not get back all the 26 pages, but the base number will be something like 4 pages per fragment or index.  That gives you an idea of what you'll get.

Comment: I am sorry, I was totally drunk when I wrote the question, the process I was thinking about was shrinking the table, not truncating it.